# Does avoiding individual variables speed up JavaScript performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

It is common in `JavaScript` to avoid unnecessary variables, as it reduces the size of `JS` codes, though readability of defining individual variables is better. In a simple example,

```
var e=document.getElementById('text');
var text=e.innerHTML;
var d=document.getElementById('test');
d.innerHTML=text;
```

this can be reduced to

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
```

I wonder if this has any benefit from performance point of view. Does avoiding excess variables reduce memory usage and enhance process speed?

Is it a serious issue? and it is always recommended to minimize the `JS` code by avoiding individual variables?

Comment: *Is it a serious issue?* No. If you do it *only* because of "performance" you're micro-optimizing.

Comment: In the example you've given, there really is not much need to - the latter is perfectly readable.  **Do what is most readable** though, unless it comes down to some core function that is called hundreds of times per second.  In that case, look for the biggest gains first - it probably won't be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical difference between the two. Most Javascript interpreters are likely to generate an equivalent internal representation for both, and the overhead of the functions and properties you're using in this example (particularly assigning to `innerHTML`!) is vastly greater than any difference you'd be likely to see.

Comment: My only concern is that the variables might be unwittingly captured by a long-lived closure (creating a leak), depending on how good the JavaScript interpreter is.